# Script in function to write find second smallest value if smallest value fulfills a particular condition

Tags: python, numpy, loops, sorting, iteration

For a set of matrices that I have, called distance_matrix (these exist in a function that then generates all of them over a given range). I need to find the smallest value in this matrix, obviously notated by an index pair,for which i have this code:

```
min_indices = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(np.abs(distance_matrix)),np.shape(distance_matrix))
```

This works perfectly well. But now i need to write something that finds the second lowest value if the indices returned by the above code is (0,0). I guess i cant use the code above, since you cant modify it to find the next value (as far as i can tell). Ive tried with an if-loop, but thats not quite working:

```
sdiff = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(distance_matrix)))
rising_1 = (sdiff == 2) 
rising_2 = (sdiff[:-1] == 1) & (sdiff[1:] == 1) 
rising_all = rising_1 
rising_all[1:] = rising_all[1:] | rising_2 
min_ind = np.where(rising_all)[0] + 1 
minima = list(zip(min_ind, distance_matrix[min_ind]))
for ind_pair in range(0,len(minima)):
    if ind_pair ==(0,0):
        minima=sorted(minima, key=lambda pair: pair[1])[1]
    else:
        minima=sorted(minima, key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
```

Comment: First sort the array using s = np.sort(original.ravel()). Then find the kth minimum. Find it's index using np.where(original==required_num)

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde. Or use argsort and just keep track of the index. Better yet, use argpartition

Comment: @Mad Physicist yep that is better

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the distance matrix is 2 dimensional then, and using the following test data:

```py
distance_matrix = np.array([[0. , 1. , 2. ],
                            [1. , 0.5, 1.5],
                            [2. , 1.5, 2. ]])
```

Now,

```py
np.unravel_index(
  np.argmin(np.abs(distance_matrix)),
  np.shape(distance_matrix)
)
```

returns `(0, 0)` for you, which is what you don't want, of course. But is there a reason you can't just make that impossible by using the following:

```py
mask = np.ones(np.shape(distance_matrix))
mask[0, 0] = np.nan  # you can put this in a loop if there is
                     # more than one coordinate set you don't want

distance_matrix * mask
# array([[nan, 1. , 2. ],
#        [1. , 0.5, 1.5],
#        [2. , 1.5, 2. ]])

np.unravel_index(
  np.nanargmin(np.abs(distance_matrix * mask)),
  np.shape(distance_matrix)
)
# (1, 1)
```

Note that `nanargmin` is [a version of](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmin.html) `argmin` that ignores `NaN`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indices of the first two smallest elements at once using [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). Partitioning on the second element of the array guarantees that the first element will be smaller, so you get both.

```
indices2 = np.unravel_index(
        np.argpartition(np.abs(distance_matrix), 1, None),
        distance_matrix.shape)
```

You must pass an `axis` of `None` to ravel the index instead of partitioning the columns. Otherwise you will not be able to call [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) directly on the result.

If you want each index separately:

```
i = np.argpartition(np.abs(distance_matrix), 1, None)
indices = np.unravel_index(i[0], distance_matrix.shape)
indices2 = np.unravel_index(i[1], distance_matrix.shape)
```

If you want to get more minima, you will have to [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) the left side of the array.

```
k = 5
i = np.argpartition(np.abs(distance_matrix), k, None)[:k]
i.sort()
indices = np.unravel_index(i, distance_matrix.shape)
```